# Adding a sitepage using visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a webpage using the sharepoint designer and need to add that page in sharepoint server using visual studio. This page contains the several filter webparts. I have tried to create a blank sharepoint application and successfully published the page to the SitePages folder. But, its icon is showing differently from the other files and throws an error when I try to open the same. Any idea about this error ?

The error message is as follows.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------  Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unable to generate code for a value of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.FilterValuePairCollection'.
>   This error occurred while trying to generate the property value for
>   StaticValues.
>
> Source Error:  [No relevant source lines]